# How can I deploy my mysql database on heroku rather than using its clearDB?

Tags: mysql, docker, heroku

I've tried to build my own mysql image with docker and deploy it to Heroku. However, it shows the error msg ***'Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch'***

How can I solve the problem mentionaboved? I don't want to use the clearDB of Heroku.